# Bamboo making a sound

Tags: growth, bamboo

I have some bamboo growing in three containers which total about six square feet of surface. The culms are about a half inch in diameter and six to eight feet long. I had a good number of new shoots last year, but none so far this year. However, all last year's leaves (or leaflets?) have been replaced and lots of new ones (and branches) added. It's supposedly *B. textilis* but I'm not super confident.

When I'm near the plants I hear a soft Rice Krispies sound<sup>*</sup>. When a breeze moves the leaves, etc., I hear a completely different and familiar rustling so that's not what I'm describing. Google tells me that you can hear bamboo growing. I'm skeptical. Mine takes several weeks between emergence of a new shoot and reaching full length. It's not the kind that grows as fast as feet per day. Nor is it the kind that hidden dragons run around on (I can clearly see the occasional Anole though).

Am I going crazy?

<sup>* Snap, Crackle, Pop</sup>

Comment: I'd suggest looking carefully for holes or "sawdust" from possible insect inhabitants. Not certain, but what I'd think of first.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: That was my first thought too but I don't see any signs of insect activity and the plants are very healthy.